# Where is ExecWB?

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

If I use WPF syntax:

```
<WebBrowser Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="htmlView"></WebBrowser>
```

Or if I add a `WindowsFormsHost`:

```
<WindowsFormsHost x:Name="formsHost" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

And in the CS file:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser htmlView= new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        formsHost.Child = htmlView;
        htmlView.Navigate("d:\\test.xml");
    }

    private void menuFilePageSetup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Do do");
    }
}
```

Either way, the `ExecWB` method is not exposed. So I can't port this code over from my MFC C++ CHtmlView derived class:

```
ExecWB(OLECMDID_PAGESETUP, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, NULL, NULL);
```

Am I missing something? At this point in time I can't implement my print preview / page setup / zoom functionality because I can't use `ExecWB`.

I have tried deriving my own class from the Winforms browser but it is still not listed.

Thank you.

I don't understand why in this question:

[How do I programmatically change printer settings with the WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714507/how-do-i-programatically-change-printer-settings-with-the-webbrowser-control)

It refers to `ShowPrintDialog` but even that is not listed.

Partial success! I don't know why, but now, when I use the hosted Winforms version, I can atleast see some of the methods:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser htmlView= new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        formsHost.Child = htmlView;
        htmlView.Navigate("d:\\test.xml");
    }

    private void menuFilePageSetup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        htmlView.ShowPageSetupDialog();
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        htmlView.ShowPrintPreviewDialog();
    }
}
```

But `ExecWb` is still missing for managing things like zooming. I found this:

[How do I print from the wpf WebBrowser available in .net 3.5 SP1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798494/how-do-i-print-from-the-wpf-webbrowser-available-in-net-3-5-sp1)

One of the answers:

> ```
> mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = webBrowser.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
> doc.execCommand("Print", true, null);
> ```

But even if I add a reference to the mshtml library the compiler will not let me convert from `HtmlDocument` to `IHtmlDocument2`. Eventually I got this:

[Clearing the selection in a webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282437/clearing-the-selection-in-a-webbrowser-control)

So now I know how to select all and copy to clipboard again (as long as I use the Winforms edition). However, having looked here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533049(v=vs.85).aspx

There seems to be no match for **Optical Zoom**:

```
ExecWB(OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, &vZoom, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic answer for calling `ExecWb` is to do this:

1. Use the WinForms WebBrowser control
2. Then something like `htmlView.Document.ExecCommand`

Pass in commands like:

```
SelectAll
Copy
```

for clipboard items.

There are native methods for displaying the print dialogues etc..

Only thing that does not seem to be supported is:

```
ExecWB(OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, &vZoom, NULL);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738232/zoom-in-on-a-web-page-using-webbrowser-net-control